# Tag Synonym Request: [dual-monitor] -> [multiple-monitors]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

This is relatively short...

It seems unnecessary to have both [dual-monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dual-monitors) AND [multiple-monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/multiple-monitors). The latter tag should be able to cover every question including the former as it's still more than a single monitor.

While 3+ monitors may need special cases, this distinction can be made in the answer itself.

Comment: I disagree with this one. Having two monitors usually works just fine on Ubuntu, but three can completely break the same system. 2 monitors usually only require one dedicated graphics card, while 3 or more usually need 2. In my experience, and from what I've seen on the site, 2 monitors and 3+ are very different classes.

Comment: I'm not sure why we a tag for monitor counts, I can read the question quite well, thanks.