# Are [dual-monitor] and [dualhead] the same?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There are two tags:

1. [dual-monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dual-monitor) (currently 128 questions):

   > For questions about using multiple monitors on a computer system.
2. [dualhead](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dualhead) (currently 47 questions):

   > Dualhead describes multi monitor setup with only two screens.

Do they describe the same thing and thus need to be merged (synonymised)? If so, which one should be the target?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Update: synonyms were added. Thanks to everyone who voted

Considering that the tag [multiple-monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/multiple-monitors) has 3096 questions tagged right now, we may want to make all of those synonyms of this tag.

Back to the topic.[Ubuntu Wiki articule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Multihead) and [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/multihead) article on this topic use  "Multihead" and "multi-monitor" terminology. [Gentoo Wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Xorg/Multiple_monitors) as well. So these two are definitely synonymous.  Multihead is frequently used term in context of X11, but judging from the number of questions and simple guess that non-technical users are likely to use "dual-monitor" term, I'd suggest using [dual-monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dual-monitor) as the target and [dual-head](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dual-head) as synonym.

On the tangential topic, we may want to create [multihead](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/multihead) and [multimonitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/multimonitor) ( which can become synonym of existing tag [multiple-monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/multiple-monitors)) , because the [dual-monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dual-monitor) is very much specific to using two  monitors, and yet there are other setups and ways to call it with more than two that can be done. Whether or not the later should be a  synonym of the former it's up for a discussion.

Comment: +1 for merging all of these into `multiple-monitors`. I see no reason to separate 2 monitors from any other case of >1 monitor.

Comment: @terdon I also thought so initially, but then I saw another user making a case against this: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16023/tag-synonym-request-dual-monitor-multiple-monitors#comment31665_16023

Comment: @pomsky my thinking is that tags help direct "experts" to questions they can answer. I can't really see much point in specifying the number of monitors. If you know how to set up 3, you also know how to set up 2. If you know 2 and not 3, OK, maybe you were alerted to a question you can't answer, but that's not a big deal. However, needing to follow several different tags (multihead, dual-monitor, dual-head, multiple-monitors) for what is, in essence, the same basic issue seems counter productive.

Comment: @terdon  agreed.

Comment: OK, so far only [dualscreen] is set as synonym. Can we get people on tag creation and voting please ?